# Robotifyのカウントブロックの意味

Tags: プログラミング言語

Robotifyというプログラミングソフトです。
紫色の部分 `from 4 to 2 by 1` の意味を教えてください

[image: スクリーンショット1]

小さなrobotが大きなrobotまで移動する問題です。
最初にこの画面が表示され途中から自分で考えましょう。という問題です。

[image: スクリーンショット2]

1つ目の画像のように再生すると赤丸のところまでrobotは移動します。

[image: スクリーンショット3]

Comment: robotify については私は詳しくないので直接回答できませんが、英語を素直に読めば理解できそうですが難しいでしょうか？

Comment: 変数を用いた繰り返しというのは、かなり難しいものです。多くの人が挫折するポイントです。回答を書きましたが、あの程度の解説だと、結局は解らない人には解らないでしょう。そういう物です。

Answer (score 0):

#### 意味

日本語では、「`i` を `4` から `2` まで `1` ずつカウントする」となります。

> [image: 日本語化されたブロック]

つまり、 `i` は繰り返しのたびに、`4, 3, 2` と変化します。
質問のケースだと繰り返しの中身として、

- `i`m 進む
- 右を向く

の2つが設定されているようなので、実行されるのは以下です。

- `4`m 進む
- 右を向く
- `3`m 進む
- 右を向く
- `2`m 進む
- 右を向く

#### 日本語化の方法

上のスクリーンショットに見られるように、一部のブロックと説明文章は日本語化されているようです。自身のアイコンをクリックするとプロフィール画面に遷移し、そこで表示言語の変更ができます。画面右上に言語の選択インターフェースがあります。下のスクリーンショットで「JA」になっている部分です。

> [image: 設定画面抜粋]

---

教材に対する感想:
Robotify は有料の教材のようです。これに関する質問を販売元が受け付けていないならば、学習の先ゆきは中々きびしいでしょう。詳しくないですが、おそらく Scratch などのほうが情報もあり、質問に答えてくれる人も多いかと思います。（Robotify も 一見すると Scratch ベースのようです）